# Forwarding to k8s service from outside the cluster

Tags: linux, networking, kubernetes

I have installed k8s on VM, now I can access pods via services on this VM directly due to the fact that kubelet configures iptable NAT on VM.

My goal is get access to pods by IP address of services from machine located outside the cluster (let call it `my-home-machine`). I have configured routing to k8s services IPs via master node. So I can send packets to nginx-pod, e.g., with netcat from `my-home-machine` this way:

```
netcat -zv 10.77.112.147 80
```

where 10.77.112.147 is ClusterIP of nginx-service in k8s.
From inside the nginx-pod I see this request with tcpdump:

```
17:42:55.985517 IP 10.0.10.64.56080 > 10.0.113.193.80: Flags [S], seq 3003847122, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4001672643 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:42:55.985557 IP 10.0.113.193.80 > 10.0.10.64.56080: Flags [S.], seq 3158920861, ack 3003847123, win 27760, options [mss 1400,sackOK,TS val 8954181 ecr 4001672643,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

where 10.0.10.64 is thing where k8s NAT should work (maybe I wrong, correct me please) and 10.0.113.193 is ClusterIP of nginx-pod. As you can see pod have gotten packet and send response. Further more I can catch this response on k8s-node where nginx-pod runs. Again with tcpdump:

```
21:06:24.669622 IP 10.0.113.193.http > 10.0.10.64.56080: Flags [S.], seq 475316172, ack 3702114669, win 27760, options [mss 1400,sackOK,TS val 9919609 ecr 4002638070,nop,wscale 7], length 0
21:06:25.673809 IP 10.0.113.193.http > 10.0.10.64.56080: Flags [S.], seq 475316172, ack 3702114669, win 27760, options [mss 1400,sackOK,TS val 9920614 ecr 4002638070,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

After 10.0.10.64 packet go through three more routers before it can reach `my-home-machine`. Problem is that this packet doesn't arrive to `my-home-machine` at all (I get timeout from netcat). I suspect that something wrong with 10.0.10.64, because I can ping `my-home-machine` or connect to mysql server (which runs on `my-home-machine`) from nginx-pod successfully. Any suggestions how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question, those IP addresses are "virtual" and are created via iptables wizardry. If you want to access a Kubernetes `Service` from outside the software-defined network, you'll need to use a `Service` of `type: NodePort` (or `type: LoadBalancer`, which is the same as `NodePort` only it also attempts to provision a load balancer for you), or you can use an `Ingress` resource if you already have an ingress controller running in your cluster and the `Service` is compatible with the constraints imposed by the ingress controller.

Comment: Yeah, I know about these documented approachs, but I am going to deploy multiple test stands with multiple apps on each stand in k8s. So `type: NodePort` will accompanied with ports hell. `type: LoadBalancer` is impossible, cause I don't have a cloud that I can attach to k8s. Actually, I have solved the problem already. One of routers dropped packets from 10.77.112.0/24 subnet. Everything works like a charm now =)